# How can I add a custom message to the device location request dialog on Android in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

How to add a message or show rationale to users on Android devices when requesting the device's location on a Flutter app. When using iOS, you can add a short description in the `info.plist` file that will show up when requesting device location.

xCode plist file:

[image: xCode plist file]

iOS UI display:

[image: iOS UI display]

Here is a screenshot of my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

[image: AndroidManifest.xml file]

Is it possible to add a message to this dialog that pops up for Android users when requesting device location?  Or do I have to show my own dialog/popup screen explaining the rationale for asking for the device location on Android devices?

[image: Android image]

I'm new to Flutter and any help is appreciated!

I tried adding `android:label = "Hello"` to the `uses-permission` to see if it would pop up in the dialog box but saw nothing.

Comment: which package are you using for getting device location ?

Comment: No you can't change message . That is system popup which you have to show to user to get permission But before showing that you can show some fancy dialog with your own message just to inform user that you are going to ask permission for this functionality

Comment: Hello, I am using the Geolocator package.  I was hoping to be able to add a message to the dialog like I did for iOS but it seems not possible for Android.  I will create my own personal dialog with a message before asking for permission.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
Permission.location.request();
```

this will help you pop up the permission dialog. or if you want to check permision and show dialog with your text content

```
var status = await Permission.location.status
if (status == PermissionStatus.denied)
//do some thing (ex: show dialog)
if (status == PermissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied)
//do some thing (ex: show setting)
.....and more status
```

Comment: Thank you Thang for the answer.  I don't necessarily need help popping up the dialog.  I need to see how to add a message to this dialog that pops up for Android when requesting for the device's location permissions.